# Why java is different from javascript when execute this split() function

Tags: javascript, java

In javascript

```
",,".split(",").length   // Return 3
```

But in java:

```js
",,".split(",").length   // Return 0
```

Why java ignores all empty string in between when split string with charater?

Comment: Obviously these are different languages. But it could be asked that in two languages a function created for same purpose is giving different results. It could be asked on stackoverflow and could be answered here.

Comment: Although your observation is correct, I think there is no one appart from the java/javascript language developers who can tell you 'why'. Maybe they have specified this in the documentation, although it most likely is a choice of preference. I voted to close this question as it is primarily opinion.

Answer (score 3):

Java are having two overloading functions of `String.split(..)`

```
 1. public String[] split(String regex, int limit){}
 2. public String[] split(String regex) . This equals with split(String regex, int limit = 0)
```

With `limit` parameter make `String.spit` of java flexible.
*The limit parameter controls the number of times the pattern is applied and therefore affects the length of the resulting array. If the limit n is greater than zero then the pattern will be applied at most n - 1 times, the array's length will be no greater than n, and the array's last entry will contain all input beyond the last matched delimiter. If n is non-positive then the pattern will be applied as many times as possible and the array can have any length. If n is zero then the pattern will be applied as many times as possible, the array can have any length, and trailing empty strings will be discarded.* More detail [here](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#split(java.lang.String,%20int))

So in your case with java:

```
",,".split(",").length   // Return 0
",,".split(",", -1).length   // Return 3
```

Answer (score 0):

To know why there is difference you will have to understand `split(String regex, int limit)` first.

The limit parameter controls the number of times the pattern is applied and therefore affects the length of the resulting array. And they specifically says

> If n is zero then the pattern will be applied as many times as possible, the array can have any length, and trailing empty strings will be discarded.

[java docs](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#split(java.lang.String,%20int))

Now in `split(String regex)`. This overloaded function is supposed to give the same result as above with a limit argument of zero.

> This method works as if by invoking the two-argument split method with the given expression and a limit argument of zero. Trailing empty strings are therefore not included in the resulting array.

Now on the other hand when we talk about javascript. We know there could not be any overloading in it. They made a single function and have optional parameter. If you provide limit argument it will limit on the number of splits to be found.

> Integer specifying a limit on the number of splits to be found. The split() method still splits on every match of separator, until the number of split items match the limit or the string falls short of separator.

[javascript docs from developer.mozilla.org](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/split)